# Decimal encoder for BCD

Tags: encoder

I need to find an Integrated Circuit Encoder that converts inputs (push botton) to its corresponding binary code, as in the table. Can anyone tell me any? I found something similar that was the *IC 74147*, but the same is obsolete.[image]

Comment: The 74HC147 isn't obsolete.

Comment: Could you send me the link where I can buy it? Because in my country I did not find it.

Comment: I don't know which country you're in. [Link](http://uk.farnell.com/search?st=74hc147)

Comment: Digikey serves a great many countries, and a 74HC147 costs less than 70 cents.

Comment: YOu already asked this and it was answered.... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335949/how-to-make-a-button-activate-its-corresponding-binary-address/335953#335953

Answer (score -1):

Look up something called a *priority encoder*.

However, a function like this is rarely needed in isolation.  In that case, this is something you do in firmware in the microcontroller that is already there for other reasons.

Even with no other reason, a microcontroller might be a good idea if bouncing of the buttons would cause problems.  Consider what happens while a button bounces.  The output code could possibly appear to go thru lots of states as each line toggles between 0 and its value to represent that button.

Comment: ...and when uC's are more cumbersome or expensive, a low pin-count CPLD works great.  Both solutions often help out in other parts of the circuit as well.  A programmable solution is very forgiving when incorporating downstream design changes and variations.